Devextreme datagrid lookup rowfilter загружает все строки из datasource игнорируя пагинацию и datasource lookup
в БД есть таблица с большим количеством строк, в datagrid выводится пагинация по 10 строк.
Когда в lookup столбца (у lookup есть свой datasource в котором значений всего 5) в строке с фильтром нажимаешь показать список, то datagrid datasource начинает загружать абсолютно ВСЕ строки, со всеми expands только для того что бы показать список из 5 элементов.
Я видел что в dealextreme для header Filter есть свой собственный header filter data source , а для rowfilter такого нет.
Как решить проблему чтобы rowfilter не загружал все данные, а использовал в качестве списка возможных значений данные из lookup datasource?
Данные загружаются через odatacontext
